# Adding and removing class, applying styles on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

## Problem

I'm having an issue adding and removing classes, applying styles on scroll.


Specifically, when I scroll down the page:

- The class of `is-red` is still on the first `.dot__outer` group when you scroll down the page when it should be removed, there should be one group highlighted with the `is-red` class
- There seems to be an issue with my if-statement, as the colors are remaining their default colors and not changing on scroll

## Expected behavior

**Scrolling:**

- On scroll, remove the class `is-red` on all divs with a class of `dot__outer`
- Add a class of `is-red` to the next `dot__outer` in the series after the user has scrolled past a specific panel. i.e. If a user is on panel two, the second group should be highlighted red

**Dot colors:**

- On black backgrounds, the dots and their borders should be white
- On white backgrounds, the dots and their borders should be black
- In both instances, any `dot__outer` with a class of `is-red` should be red

## scripts.js

```
$(function() {

  function updateProgress() {
    let dot = $(".dot");

    let dotsBottom = $(".dots").offset().top + $(".dots").outerHeight();
    let panelHeaderBottom =$(".panel-1").offset().top + $(".panel-1").outerHeight();
    let panelRelatedTop = $(".panel-8").offset().top;

    // If the `dot__outer` has a class of `is-active` the dot should also be red. By default, the dot and border should be white.
    if (dot.parent().hasClass("is-red")) {
      $(this).css("background", "red");
    } else {

      // If the position of the dots is less than the bottom of the header or greater than the top of the related section, the dots are white. Otherwise, the dots are black
      if (dotsBottom < panelHeaderBottom || dotsBottom > panelRelatedTop) {
        $(this).css("background", "#000");

      } else {
        $(this).css("background", "#fff");
      }
    }

    $(".panel").each(function(index) {
      let currentPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
      let panelTop = $(this).offset().top;
      let panelBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();

      if ((currentPosition > panelTop) && (currentPosition < panelBottom)) {        
        $(".dot__outer").removeClass("is-red");
        $(".dot__outer").eq(index).addClass("is-red");
      } else {
        $(".dot__outer").eq(0).addClass("is-red");
      }
    });
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    updateProgress();
  });
});
```

## index.html

```
<div class="panels">
  <div class="panel panel-1">Panel #1</div>
  <div class="panel panel-2">Panel #2</div>
  <div class="panel panel-3">Panel #3</div>
  <div class="panel panel-4">Panel #4</div>
  <div class="panel panel-5">Panel #5</div>
  <div class="panel panel-6">Panel #6</div>
  <div class="panel panel-7">Panel #7</div>
  <div class="panel panel-8">Panel #8</div>
</div>

<div class="dots">

  <div class="dot__outer is-red">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Codepen

https://codepen.io/yacoubian/pen/PBOVKw?editors=1010

**UPDATE**

Scrolling issue fixed, codpen updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. This dynamically checks the panel position and compares it to each dot position then applies a class for css styling.

**codepen**: https://codepen.io/tylerfowle/pen/QBaBgO

1. I've added a `light` and `dark` class on the panels html.
2. In the JS we detect if the panel is in the viewport, if it is what class does it have (light or dark).
3. We then loop through each of the `.dot__outer` elements and see what panel they are in, and apply the correct class. We use the midpoint to determine which panel the majority of the dot is in.

```js
$(function() {
  let dotClass = "dark";

  function updateProgress() {
    let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    let viewportBot = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    $(".panel").each(function(index) {
      // save the ref to the current panel for use in the dot loop
      let $this = $(this);
      let panelTop = $(this).offset().top;
      let panelBot = panelTop + $(this).outerHeight();

      // add class based on panel that is within viewport, remove from siblings
      if ((viewportTop > panelTop) && (viewportTop < panelBot)) {
        $(".dot__outer").eq(index).addClass("is-red").siblings().removeClass("is-red");
      }

      $(".dot__outer").each(function(){
        let dotTop = $(this).offset().top;
        let dotMid = dotTop + $(this).outerHeight()/2;
        let dotBot = dotTop + $(this).outerHeight();

        if ($this.hasClass("light")) {
          dotClass = "light";
        } else {
          dotClass = "dark";
        }

        if (panelTop < dotMid && panelBot > dotMid) {
          $(this).removeClass("dark light").addClass(dotClass);
        }

      });

    });
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    updateProgress();
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.panel {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
}
.panel.panel-1, .panel.panel-8 {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.dots {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 48px;
  right: 48px;
}

.dot {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dot__outer {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.dot__outer.light {
  border-color: black;
}
.dot__outer.light .dot {
  background: black;
}
.dot__outer.dark {
  border-color: white;
}
.dot__outer.dark .dot {
  background: white;
}
.dot__outer.is-red {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
.dot__outer.is-red .dot {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panels">
  <div class="panel panel-1 dark">Panel #1</div>
  <div class="panel panel-2 light">Panel #2</div>
  <div class="panel panel-3 light">Panel #3</div>
  <div class="panel panel-4 light">Panel #4</div>
  <div class="panel panel-5 light">Panel #5</div>
  <div class="panel panel-6 light">Panel #6</div>
  <div class="panel panel-7 light">Panel #7</div>
  <div class="panel panel-8 dark">Panel #8</div>
</div>

<div class="dots">

  <div class="dot__outer is-red">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *each* nested inside another *each* and everything will run on *each* scroll movement .. the browser will suffer ...

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach that you might take:

```
function updateProgress() {
    let dotsBottom = $(".dots").offset().top + $(".dots").outerHeight();
    let dotBorder = $(".dot__outer");

    let headerBottom = $(".panel-1").offset().top + $(".panel-1").outerHeight();
    let relatedTop = $(".panel-8").offset().top;

    $(".panel").each(function(index) {
        let currentPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        let panelTop = $(this).offset().top;
        let panelBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();

        if (currentPosition > panelTop && currentPosition < panelBottom) {
            dotBorder.removeClass("is-red");
            dotBorder.eq(index).addClass("is-red").children().css("background", "red");

            if (dotsBottom < headerBottom || dotsBottom > relatedTop) {
                dotBorder.not(".is-red").children().css("background", "#fff");
            } else {
                dotBorder.not(".is-active").children().css("background", "#000");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably solve some of the issues using CSS, especially the coloration part.

Here is an idea where I reduced the JS code to only add/remove the class based on a simple division to find the index.

Then, I used some CSS trick to have the coloration of the boxes:

- For the border, I used a `box-shadow` to create a second border with a different color so that only one will be visible depending on the background.
- For the background, I defined a coloration using gradient that is the invert coloration of the site. I made it fixed and I adjusted the position on scroll with a CSS variable.

*Run the snippet on full page for better experience*

```js
$(function() {

  function updateProgress() {
        let currentPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        let index = Math.floor(currentPosition/$(window).height());
        
        $(".is-red").removeClass("is-red");
        $(".dot__outer").eq(index).addClass("is-red");
        $('.dot').css('--p',(-currentPosition)+'px');
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    updateProgress();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.panel {
  height: 100vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
}

.panel.panel-1,
.panel.panel-8 {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.dots {
  position: fixed;
  top: 48px;
  right: 48px;
}

.dot {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom,
      #fff 0%,#fff 12.5%,
      #000 12.5%,#000 87.5%,
      #fff 87.5%,#fff 100%) no-repeat;
  background-size:200vw 800vh;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:0 calc(var(--p,48px) + 48px);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dot__outer {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 8px;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #000,
             -1px 1px 0px #000,
             1px -1px 0px #000,
             -1px -1px 0px #000;
}

.dot__outer.is-red {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 0px red,
             -1px 1px 0px red,
             1px -1px 0px red,
             -1px -1px 0px red;
}

.dot__outer.is-red .dot {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="panels">
  <div class="panel panel-1">Panel #1</div>
  <div class="panel panel-2">Panel #2</div>
  <div class="panel panel-3">Panel #3</div>
  <div class="panel panel-4">Panel #4</div>
  <div class="panel panel-5">Panel #5</div>
  <div class="panel panel-6">Panel #6</div>
  <div class="panel panel-7">Panel #7</div>
  <div class="panel panel-8">Panel #8</div>
</div>

<div class="dots">

  <div class="dot__outer is-red">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__outer">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like this does fix the adding and removing of class issue on scroll. Is there another approach you could take instead of using that box-shadow in CSS?

Comment: @MaryYacoubian well, it's the easiest way I found as with JS it would need a lot of complex calculation ... You want something else with CSS or you don't want CSS at all?

Comment: I've updated my Codepen. The only issue now is that on black backgrounds, the dots need to be white. I've added in this line `$(".dot__outer").not(".is-red").children().css("background", "#000");` But I feel there's problem an if-statement I'm missing somewhere.

Comment: @MaryYacoubian but don't update the question :) you need to keep with all the issue initialy or my answer will have no meaning

Comment: @MaryYacoubian well, I have found a solution for the dots using CSS if intrested ... the JS one is not intuitive, we should do complex calculation, it's not only and if else

Comment: I think I've solved it based on your original solution.

Comment: @MaryYacoubian I have also reduced the JS code, no need an each function .. a simple division is enough to get the index ;)

Comment: @TylerFowle which is the case ;) 100vh for all the panel = screen height

Answer (score -1):

I am still learning javascript but I do know that Bootstrap has [ScrollSpy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/) which will do this for you using what is already in the bootstrap.js. These tutorials may help you out as well if you do not want to switch theme to Bootstrap.

- [Page scroll to an ID](http://manos.malihu.gr/page-scroll-to-id-with-mousewheel-and-keyboard/)
- See the Code Pen "Scroll Position Indicators" by Zachary Olson. Here is the last part of the URL `codepen.io/zacharyolson/pen/uaEzD`
- Changing page color on scroll in JS Fiddle - `jsfiddle.net/ncuydr9y/1`

Comment: Based on the links you shared, do you mind posting a code snippet that helps to address the original question? It is not particularly clear what that Codepen is doing.